# issue submitting score to a leaderboard

Tags: iphone

i have enabled `Game Center` in my itunes connect for my app.
In my game center, i have created a leaderboard named "Level 1" with its id "level1", integer.

In my game, i try to submit a score like this:

```
 NSAutoreleasePool   *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"level1"] autorelease];

    int64_t score1 =scr;
    scoreReporter.value = score1;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) { 
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Submit failed");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Score Submited");
        }
    }];

    [pool release];
```

but i get a **submit failed**; i've created the leaderboard about 30-40 mins ago, could it not be enabled yet by apple? if else, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Here is my error:

> Error: Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=6 "The requested operation
>   could not be completed because local player has not been
>   authenticated." UserInfo=0x1ed4d4a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The
>   requested operation could not be completed because local player has
>   not been authenticated.}

btw i have internet access on my iphone and am connected on my phone to an apple account

Comment: Have you tried reading the error? What's the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't authentificated in game center, now it works!

Example from [Game Center Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html):

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
         if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
         {
             // Player was successfully authenticated.
             // Perform additional tasks for the authenticated player.
         }
     }];
}
```